# Failed to request IAM token for Kubernetes on Bluemix

Tags: kubernetes, containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

I have provisioned a Kubernetes cluster on Bluemix US. When I try to follow the instructions to login and use Bluemix CLI to interact with it I get the following error message "Requesting LPTA cookie... OK Requesting IAM token... FAILED Failed to request IAM token: The provided client id is not authorized for the required grant type"

Answer (score 1):

Please provide output from `bx login`, `bx cs init`, and `bx cs cluster-config <cluster-name>`.

Alternatively, if you already have `kubectl` installed, you can set the KUBECONFIG env variable to point to your cluster config and use `kubectl config use-context` to switch contexts to the correct cluster. Bluemix allows you to download kubeconfig files and auth certs directly to your machine from the Access tab for your Kubernetes cluster in the Bluemix Dashboard. This approach allows you to avoid the Bluemix client altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using the `cs-cli` plugin.

Uninstalling the `cs-cli` plugin and installing the `container-service` plugin instead fixed it for me.

```
bx plugin uninstall cs-cli
bx plugin install container-service -r Bluemix
```